# Add column with default value from a previous select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a value which I get like this:

```
select myValue from myTable where id=5
```

I want to add an `nvarchar` column to another table where the default value will be the previous one.

But I cannot see how to stock this previous value to use it in my adding column script :

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'NewColumn' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'MySecondTable'))
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE MySecondTable
   ADD    NewColumn nvarchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'my previous value'     
END
GO
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL to the rescue:

```
DECLARE @defval NVARCHAR(500)=LEFT((SELECT myValue FROM myTable where id=5),250);
SET @defval=REPLACE(@defval,N'''',N''''''); -- double single quotes for dynamic SQL statements
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'
  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE [name]=N''NewColumn'' AND [object_id]=OBJECT_ID(N''MySecondTable''))
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE MySecondTable
    ADD NewColumn nvarchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT N'''+@defval+'''
  END;
';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;
```

Comment: @user2443476 Note that it is best to **name** your constraints, so that when you need to script changes later you don't have to deal with random names assigned by SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @default nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @default = myValue from myTable WHERE id=5

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'NewColumn' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'MySecondTable'))
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = '
   ALTER TABLE MySecondTable
   ADD    NewColumn nvarchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''' + @default+''''
   EXEC sp_executesql @SQL     
END
GO
```